# System of $n$ nonlinear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I'm trying to model the following system of $n$ nonlinear differential equations:

$$
\dot{P}_i(t) = \sum_{1 \, \leq \, j \, < \, i} R(p_{ji}) - A(p_{ji}) + \sum_{i \, < \, j \, \leq \, N} A(p_{ij}) - R(p_{ij}) \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1, \ldots, N
$$

where $p_{ij} = P_j - P_i$, $A(p_{ij}) = \dfrac{ap_{ij}}{e^{bp_{ij}}}$ and $R(p_{ij}) = \dfrac{c}{p_{ij}}$.

The following code solves this system of $n$ nonlinear differential equations in one dimension (for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\, \geq \, 2}$):

```
p[i_, j_] = P[j][t] - P[i][t];
A@p[j, i] = (a*p[j, i])/Exp[b*p[j, i]];
R@p[j, i] = c/p[j, i];
summand1 = R@p[j, i] - A@p[j, i];
A@p[i, j] = (a*p[i, j])/Exp[b*p[i, j]];
R@p[i, j] = c/p[i, j];
summand2 = A@p[i, j] - R@p[i, j];
n = 12;

sys = Table[P[i]'[t] == Sum[If[j < i, summand1, 0], {j, 1, n}] + 
Sum[If[i < j, summand2, 0], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys, P[1][0] == 1, P[2][0] == 1.01, P[3][0] == 1.02, 
P[4][0] == 5, P[5][0] == 6.8, P[6][0] == 6.9, P[7][0] == 7, P[8][0] == 7.2, P[9][0] == 8.9, 
P[10][0] == 10, P[11][0] == 10.25, P[12][0] == 11}, P /@ Range[12], {t, 0, 100}, {a, b, c}];

Manipulate[Plot[sol[a, b, c][t] // Through // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, 1}, .1, 10}, {{b, 1}, .1, 10}, 
{{c, .1}, .1, 100}, {{T, 1}, .1, 100}]
```

Edit:

After taking out the errors I got the following in two dimensions :

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

n = 5;

P[i_][t_] = {X[i][t], Y[i][t]};

p[j_, i_] = Norm[P[i][t] - P[j][t]];

A@p[j, i] = (a*(P[i][t] - P[j][t]))/Exp[b*p[j, i]];

R@p[j, i] = (c*(P[i][t] - P[j][t]))/p[j, i]^2;

summand1 = R@p[j, i] - A@p[j, i];

A@p[i, j] = (a*(P[j][t] - P[i][t]))/Exp[b*p[i, j]];

R@p[i, j] = (c*(P[j][t] - P[i][t]))/p[i, j]^2;

summand2 = A@p[i, j] - R@p[i, j];

sys = Table[
   D[P[i][t], t] == 
    Sum[If[j < i, summand1, 0], {j, 1, n}] + 
     Sum[If[i < j, summand2, 0], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys, P[1][0] == {1, 1}, 
    P[2][0] == {1, 6}, P[3][0] == {1, -1}, P[4][0] == {5, 3}, 
    P[5][0] == {6, 2}}, 
   Table[P[i][t], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 5}, {a, b, c}];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[sol[a, b, c][t] // Through // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, 1}, .1, 5}, {{b, 1}, .1, 5}, {{c, .1}, .1, 
  5}, {{T, 1}, 0, 5}]
```

The only thing is that there's no output.

Comment: Mathematica is complaining about the ambiguity of `p'[i, t]`. Should that derivative be taken with respect to $t$ or $i$? You should specify that, e.g. by writing `Derivative[p[i, t], t]` instead. If you do that, it returns a result. Even then, though, when you try to provide parameter values, it indicates that your system is underdetermined.

Comment: 1. If you have $n$ equation to solve, then you need to generate them explicitly with e.g. `Table`. 2. When $i=1$ and $i=N$, what's the ODE?

Comment: The ODE becomes $p_1'(t) = \sum_{j \, = \, 2}^N A(p_{1j}) - R(p_{1j})$. The table we tried to generate in the comment below gives multiple errors, unfortunately. If we can get it working we'll have a nested sum with only one rule, namely $i \neq j$.

Comment: …Why do you think this code piece will have a chance to work? _Mathematica_ is flexible, but it still has clear and strict syntax, you can not write code in such wild way. Please think about how to generate the equation system with e.g. `Table`.

Comment: @MarcoB I think you mean `D[p[i, t], t]`, right?

Comment: Get rid of the extraneous `[t]`: `sol[a, b, c] // Evaluate`.  Evaluate `sol[1, 1, 1]` separately to see what you get.  It should give you a big hint why an extra `[t]` & `Through` cause trouble.

Comment: This resulted in the desired output. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* is flexible, but you can not write code in such wild way. You'd better spend some time learning the basic of the core language first. The following is a working example, which is just a simple use case of `Table`:

```
p[i_, j_] = P[j][t] - P[i][t]
A@p[i, j] = (a p[i, j])/Exp[b p[j, i]]
R@p[i, j] = c/p[i, j]
summand = R@p[i, j] - A@p[i, j]

Ν = 3;    
sys = Table[
  P[i]'[t] == Sum[If[i == j, 0, summand], {j, 1, Ν}], {i, 1, Ν}]

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys, P[1][0] == 0, P[2][0] == 0.5, P[3][0] == 1}, 
  P /@ Range[3], {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, c}]

lst = sol[-1/10, -1/10, -1/10]

ParametricPlot3D[lst[t] // Through // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This answer was helpful in modelling the one-dimensional case. Unfortunately, I can't seem a way to define `P[i][t]={X[i][t],Y[i][t]}` to model the two-dimensional case. Should we consider, as in 1D, `i` as a variable or not?

Comment: @E4M2227601 As a starting point, execute `{sys, P[1][0] == {1, 1}, P[2][0] == {1, 6}, P[3][0] == {1, -1}, 
P[4][0] == {5, 3}, P[5][0] == {6, 2}}` and observe the output, and think about what's wrong here.

Comment: I made a correction by redefining `P[i]'[t]` as `D[P[i][t], t]` and replaced the the initial conditions `P[i][0]` with `{X[i][0],Y[i][0]}`. The equations are now in `X[i][t]` when executing `{sys, {X[1][0], Y[1][0]} == {1, 1}, {X[2][0], Y[2][0]} == {1, 
   6}, {X[3][0], Y[3][0]} == {1, -1}, {X[4][0], Y[4][0]} == {5, 
   3}, {X[5][0], Y[5][0]} == {6, 2}}` but there are no functions specified for output from `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: @E4M2227601 Now execute `P /@ Range[5]` and observe, and think about what's wrong.

Comment: Corrected as `{X /@ Range[5], Y /@ Range[5]}`. There are no more errors, but the plot is empty. I need to generate `{X[i],Y[i]}` instead of `{X[1],...,X[5],Y[1],...,Y[5]}`

Comment: When the code doesn't work as expected, you should calm down, decompose the code as much as possible and locate the source of problem (as I've done in my last 2 comment).

Comment: It returns `{X[1][t], Y[1][t]}` for `P[1][t]`, but `P[1][0]` for `P[1][0]` for example. So it doesn't see `t` as variable. How do we define `t` also as a variable in order to get expressions for `{X[i][t], Y[i][t]}` instead of `{X[i], Y[i]}`. Is it valid to define `P[i_][t_] = {X[i][t], Y[i][t]}`?

Comment: 1. Check the document of `Table` carefully. 2. Why not simply try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Since i,j are just subscripts you should use them as array indices.
For example:

```
P[t_] := Table[p[t][[j]] - p[t][[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
A[a_, b_, t_] := Table[a*P[t][[i,j]]*Exp[b*P[t][[i,j]]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
.
.
.
summ = ... Sum[Sum[... A[a, b, t][[i,j]] ..., {i, 1, N}], {j, 1, N}]
```

and so on...

Comment: Then, how do you tell mathematica that $j \neq i$ and that the summations are between $1 \leq j < i$ and $i < j \leq N$ (because the range of $j$ is clearly not from $1$ to $N$). Furthermore, I do not understand what summ is.

Comment: You can just redefine array components where $j<i$ as zeros.
Summ is just an example how to sum an array with 2 indices.

Comment: The first line of your code gives multiple errors, i.e. Part 2 and Part 3 of P[t] does not exist (according to Mathematica).